# Is there an easier way in Hive to consolidate different JSON keys as one?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to parse json string using Hive and I noticed that there are two different keys for some values such as:

```
get_json_object(json_string, '$.user_name')
get_json_object(json_string, '$.User_Name')
```

Is there a way to check if one key or the another exists and then just insert the value into a parse table?

My current script selects both and inserts into a table then another script that checks if either one of the key's values are null and perform case when statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  coalesce
        (
            get_json_object(json_string, '$.user_name')
           ,get_json_object(json_string, '$.User_Name')
        ) as username

from    tbl_something
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
Select 
   CASE WHEN get_json_object(json_string, '$.user_name') is not null THEN get_json_object(json_string, '$.user_name')
   ELSE get_json_object(json_string, '$.User_Name')
   END AS username
FROM tbl_something;
```